# iOS application repeatedly rejected from Apple store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm facing some problems with uploading an iOS application to the Apple store. For the very first time, I uploaded and submitted my iOS application and it was rejected by the Apple team. They mentioned that they want authentication for my application, so I put authentication and uploaded my binary again. It was rejected a second time. This time they mentioned that I need to put authentication in my application. That's when I realized that my application is not getting updated.

The first time I made changes, I used the Organizer in Xcode to upload my binary (navigate to Organizer -> Archives. Then validate first and distribute).

The second time I made changes, I used the Organizer to upload my updated binary again.

However in all cases my binary is not being updated. How cam I fix this problem, it is a real headache for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to supply that authentication data within the iTunesConnect review information. There are specific fields named

> Demo Account Information

and

> Review Notes

Fill in that account information within that first field.

Comment: Hi Till, Thanks for ur answer. when i want to upload my binary for second time using XCode, do i need to archive again? What is different between XCode and Application loader ?

Comment: I prefer using the Application Loader. What I do is: 1. build an app-store version using a schema that I prepared for that purpose. 2. right-click the resulting product and select show in finder. 3. right-click the app-bundle and compress (ZIP). 4. use the application loader and upload that ZIP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the archive date in Organizer before you submit binary to App Store. When ever you make any changes to app Archive it again to reflect changes on your binary. Otherwise your binary won't reflect changes you made on code.

Answer (score 0):

Apps that are “beta”, “demo”, “trial”, or “test” versions will be rejected. If you use any word related to these in the content , name etc. will be rejected.

Secondly Pay special attention when you are using any social networking site information in your app. e.g suppose if you got many permissions from Facebook but you are not using that information in your app your app will reject. So be precise while using permissions from social networking sites.

Apple once rejected my app because i violated the iCloud deal of unpacking 2MB data from app bundle into the file system. So for downloading data more than 2MB should not create any backup. For this you can use non-user data, cache storage or mark it with “Do Not Backup”.

Hope that helps!!